dependency of signals and eventstream(s)
The code creates 4 rectangles, creating a stacked bar ranging from 0 to 100, and 4 triangles I want to use as sliders that can be used to change the size of the rectangles.
The range covered by the rectangles can become less than 100, but not more than 100
The logic of the sliders should be like this

each slider can be moved to zero, making the width of its rectangle 0
when a slider moves to the left, its rectangle becomes smaller, the rectangles on right do not grow. They only move to the left
as soon as a slider passes (or hits meaning <=) a slider to the left, the rectangle of the slider becomes zero
When a slider moves to the right, its rectangle becomes larger. All rectangles begin to become smaller, starting with the rightmost rectangle, or vanish completely.

An example:
When the leftmost slider is moved from 25 to 55 the width of the
left rectangle becomes 55
the width of the 2nd rectangle does not change
the width of the 3 rectangles shrinks from 25 to 20 as the total width of the "bar" can not grow beyond 100.
I'm wondering if this is possible at all.
Any hint or improvement on my code is very much appreciated if this can be achieved.
My code
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 50,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "base",
      "values": [

        {"y": "range", "class": "class 1", "x": 25},
        {"y": "range", "class": "class 2", "x": 25},
        {"y": "range", "class": "class 3", "x": 25},
        {"y": "range", "class": "class 4", "x": 25}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "control",
      "source": "base",
      "transform": [

        {"type": "formula", "as": "x", 
        "expr": "datum.class =='class 1'? tri_mark_1_width : datum.x"
        },

        {"type": "formula", "as": "x", 
        "expr": "datum.class === 'class 2' && tri_mark_1_width > tri_mark_2_width ? 0 : datum.c === 'class 2' && tri_mark_1_width < tri_mark_2_width ? tri_mark_2_width - tri_mark_1_width : datum.x"
        },

        {"type": "formula", "as": "x", 
        "expr": "datum.class === 'class 3' && tri_mark_3_width === 0 ? 0 : datum.class === 'class 3' && tri_mark_1_width + tri_mark_2_width <= tri_mark_3_width ? tri_mark_3_width - tri_mark_2_width : datum.x"
        }
        ,
        {"type": "formula", "as": "x", 
        "expr": "datum.class === 'class 4' && tri_mark_4_width === 0 ? 0 : datum.class === 'class 4' && tri_mark_1_width + tri_mark_2_width + tri_mark_3_width <= tri_mark_4_width ? 100- tri_mark_4_width : datum.x"
        },      


        {"type": "stack", "groupby": ["y"], "field": "x"}
      ]
    }
  ],
   "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_1_slider",
      "value": 25, 
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@tri_mark_1:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, 100))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "tri_mark_1_width", "update": "clamp(tri_mark_1_slider, 0, 100)"},
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_1_mouseover",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {"events": "@tri_mark_1:mousedown", "update": "true"},
        {"events": "window:mouseup", "update": "false"}
      ]
    },
    
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_2_slider",
      "value": 50, 
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@tri_mark_2:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, 100))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "tri_mark_2_width", "update": "clamp(tri_mark_2_slider, 0, 100)"},
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_2_mouseover",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {"events": "@tri_mark_2:mousedown", "update": "true"},
        {"events": "window:mouseup", "update": "false"}
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "tri_mark_3_slider",
      "value": 75, 
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@tri_mark_3:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, 100))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "tri_mark_3_width", "update": "clamp(tri_mark_3_slider, 0, 100)"},
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_3_mouseover",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {"events": "@tri_mark_3:mousedown", "update": "true"},
        {"events": "window:mouseup", "update": "false"}
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "tri_mark_4_slider",
      "value": 100, 
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@tri_mark_4:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "invert('x', clamp(x(), 0, 100))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "tri_mark_4_width", "update": "clamp(tri_mark_4_slider, 0, 100)"},
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_4_mouseover",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {"events": "@tri_mark_4:mousedown", "update": "true"},
        {"events": "window:mouseup", "update": "false"}
      ]
    }
   
   
   ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "control", "field": "y"}
    },
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "control", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["#EBD423", "#5744AB", "#4823EB", "#968D48"],
      "domain": {"data": "control", "field": "class"}
    }
  ],


  "axes": [
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y", "ticks": false},
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x", "ticks": false}
  ],


  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "control"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
          "height": {"scale": "y", "band": 1, "offset": -1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "y0"},
          "x2": {"scale": "x", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "class"}
      
      ,"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_1",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value":0, "offset": -7},
          "color": "red",
          "shape": {"value": "triangle-down"},
          "size": {"value": 400},
          "stroke": {"value": "#EBD423"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "tri_mark_1_width"},
          "fill": {"signal": "tri_mark_1_mouseover ? '#EBD423' : '#fffff0'"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "#EBD423"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tri_mark_2",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value":0, "offset": -7},
          "shape": {"value": "triangle-down"},
          "size": {"value": 400},
          "stroke": {"value": "#5744AB"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "tri_mark_2_width"},
          "fill": {"signal": "tri_mark_2_mouseover ? '#5744AB' : '#fffff0'"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "#5744AB"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "name": "tri_mark_3",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value":0, "offset": -7},
          "shape": {"value": "triangle-down"},
          "size": {"value": 400},
          "stroke": {"value": "#4823EB"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "tri_mark_3_width"},
          "fill": {"signal": "tri_mark_3_mouseover ? '#4823EB' : '#fffff0'"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "#4823EB"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "name": "tri_mark_4",
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "y": {"scale": "y", "value":0, "offset": -7},
          "shape": {"value": "triangle-down"},
          "size": {"value": 400},
          "stroke": {"value": "#968D48"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "signal": "tri_mark_4_width"},
          "fill": {"signal": "tri_mark_4_mouseover ? '#968D48' : '#fffff0'"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "#968D48"},
          "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Have you seen this which looks similar and could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601778/how-to-change-width-of-bar-chart-by-slider-in-vega/

Hey, yes I did! But in some it's different. There is only one slider, that stops at 40. My sliders can all go to the left to 0 and then these rectangles should vanish. But in my current solution, i have an issue with the last slider, as the rightmos rectangle does not change its size. So I'm wondering, if it's my code or some limitation.
I'm also wondering if the sequence definition plays a role, e.g., can the right "slider" trigger the sliders 1 to 3?
